# Next.js Link Component (as props) not working as intended

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Next.js Link Component (as props) not working

I would like to create modal routing in my Nextjs project (using app router). When clicking on one of the item, it will be open in a modal instead of routing to another view.

I have a dynamic route like this:

```
/explore/[recipeId]
```

Each item will be a Nextjs `Link` component, once click it will open the modal.

```
<Link
  href={`/explore/?recipeId=${id}`}
  as={`/explore/${id}`}
></Link>
```

In the explore page file (`explore/page.js`), the modal will open when it detect the existence of the query params.

```
<Modal visible={!!recipeId}>
  <Recipe id={recipeId as string} />
</Modal>
```

My expectation:

- Browser shows the url as `http://localhost:3000/explore/[id]` after click
- Modal is open (no redirect)

But when I test the behavior, what I get was:

- Browser shows the url as `http://localhost:3000/explore/[id]` after click
- Modal is **not open**

The situaiton is like `href` is being ignored by the `Link` Component when `as` props exist. It will route to the url mentioned in the `as` props instead (not rendering what `href` is pointing to).

I had tried changing `as` prop to some random params like `/random`, it will result into *404* instead of rendering `/explore/[id]` page in a modal.

Not sure if I had misuderstand about the usage of `as` props in Nextjs `Link` component. Appreciate any help given.